# MongoJack MongoDB Scala Optional ObjectId Not Working

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, mongo-jackson-mapper, mongojack

Hi I have my case class defined as so

```
case class bread (
  @ObjectId @JsonProperty("_id") id: Option[String] = None,
  @JsonProperty("yeast_level") yeastLevel: Int,
  @JsonProperty("name") name: String
)
```

My Json looks like this

```
{
  "id": "1923109230",
  "yeastLevel": 4,
  "name": "apple"
}
```

and I first parse the json into a Bread object

When I try to insert the bread object into mongodb thru the MongoJack it keeps giving me an exception.

```
org.mongojack.MongoJsonMappingException: Error mapping BSON to POJOs
```

When I put an option around the other two fields like that it does not result in the exception. Can you not make the objectId optional?

Help appreciated and thanks

Comment: Or the [Play JSON support for ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/play.html) could be used

Comment: hi @cchantep do you mean use that instead of mongojack? I will need to use mongojack at present time...